# A third-party turned over information about me to a party in a case that I am not involved in. What recourse do I have?

Tags: united-states, privacy, civil-law, arizona, subpoena

A civil lawsuit is going on that I am not a party to. The Plaintiff in that case issued a subpoena to a third-party company whose services I use. The third-party company contacted me and informed me that they received a subpoena that demands certain information about me.

I reached out to the Defendant and I was told that the Defendant is contesting the subpoenas and requesting that they be quashed. Once the motion was filed by the Defendant, I forwarded them to the third-party.

I've now discovered that the third-party provided a lot my personal information to the Plaintiff, even information that is not even remotely connected to the litigation.

What recourse do I have?

Comment: Outside certain types of information, the US has very lax privacy laws. Medical information is protected by HIPAA, financial information by things like PCI. Lawyers have professional codes of confidentiality. IANAL, but I think anything else would depend on the contract you have with the third party.

Comment: What is the problem with your information being disclosed to the plaintiff? Are you suffering losses? Are you defamed?

Comment: You did it wrong, you should have filed an objection directly with the court, and the judge would have considered it. If it was denied, your recourse would be to appeal to a higher court.

Answer (score 4):

### None

Even in countries with high privacy protections, there is no privacy breach where the disclosure is mandated by law. A person served with a subpoena must comply or contest; complying is not a privacy breach.